# Multiple filters with list js plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, filtering

I am trying to create multiple filters for a list of products with the plugin list.js, i.e. I want to filter a list by both colour and item, at the moment the code below just does the filtering for red items how can I change it so that if the user chooses both a colour and an item, it filters correctly?

```
      <form id="filter">
         <select id ="colour" name="colour">
          <option value="0">All packages</option>
        <option value="1">Red</option>
        <option value="2" >Yellow</option>
        <option value="3" >Green</option>
    </select>
    <select id ="items" name="items">
        <option value="0">All items</option>
        <option value="1" >T-shirt</option>
        <option value="2">Trousers</option>
        <option value="3" >Jumper</option>

    </select>
</form>

$('#filter-clothes').click(function() {
        featureList.filter(function(item) {
            if (item.values().colour == "Red") {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume #filter-clothes is a button user clicks to apply the filter.

```
$('#filter-clothes').on('click', function() {
    var colorFilter = $('#colour').text();
    var itemFilter = $('#items').text(); 

    featureList.filter(function(item) {
        return 
            (colorFilter==='All packages' || item.values().colour === colorFilter) 
            && (itemFilter==='All items' || item.values().item === itemFilter);
    });

    return false;
});
```

You'll want to flesh it out by only applying the filters when there is a value selected for the colour or item dropdowns.

EDIT: Here is a version with some console.log() calls that should help you figure out why it only works when you use || (OR) instead of && (AND):

```
$('#filter-clothes').on('click', function() {
    var colorFilter = $('#colour').text();
    var itemFilter = $('#items').text(); 

    console.log('colorFilter: ' + colorFilter);
    console.log('itemFilter : ' + itemFilter);
    console.log('Applying filter now...');

    featureList.filter(function(item) {
        console.log('Running filter() on item: ('+item+')');
        console.log('item.values().colour: ' + item.values().colour);
        console.log('item.values().item: ' + item.values().item);

        return 
            (colorFilter==='All packages' || item.values().colour === colorFilter) 
            && (itemFilter==='All items' || item.values().item === itemFilter);
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Giscard, the logic looks correct but it didn't work, I think because $('#colour').val(); gets the actual value of the option i.e. the attribute value and not the text within it, how could I amend that? Thanks

Comment: Use .text() instead of .val()

Comment: Thanks it actually worked but with || (OR) instead of && (AND) .Only thing I need now is to show all the products when they click on all for colours and all for items. ie. option value=0 for colours and option value = 0 for items, how can I write that? Thanks!

Comment: Well it's a little weird if you use OR, normally if I filter something by two different criteria, I expect it to work with AND, not OR. But if that's what you want here, then by all means use the OR. I updated the answer to show all products if they select the 'All' option for either color or items (because you are using OR, choosing 'All' option in one droplist will render any value in the other droplist moot).

Comment: you're right I'm sorry, I did want to use AND, but I tried using that code with the && and no results appear at all, it only works with || (or), any ideas why it might be? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know, I couldn't say without knowing more about featureList and the rest of your code. Why don't you debug it by adding some calls to console.log() inside the function you pass to the `.filter()` function?

Comment: If you require further help, can you please post more of the code? Post the code for featureList. Your problem might be with the properties available on whatever `item.values()` is returning.

Comment: sorry it actually does work, but how can I change it so that when only one of the select boxes is "all packages" or "all categories" and other the one does have a value. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the html, or other functions like `values()` you probably want to get the cureent values from the select tags

```
$('#filter-clothes').click(function() {
       var color=$('#colour').val(), itemVal=$('#items').val();
         /* not sure what you expect "item" to be, is index but used your same code*/  
        featureList.filter(function(item) {
           /* not sure what XXX property is for items*/
            return item.values().colour == color && tem.values().XXXXX==itemVal; 

        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Charlie but that would only filter by colour, and I want to filter by both colour and items

Comment: OK  need to add the second filer with an `&&` in the `if` so it matches both . Getting other value done same wayI forgot about second filter

Comment: Thanks it actually worked but with || (OR) instead of && (AND) .Only thing I need now is to show all the products when they click on all for colours and all for items. ie. option value=0 for colours and option value = 0 for items, how can I write that? Thanks!

Comment: change handler for the select tags... check if one or other value is null, then reset the list??

Comment: I tried this but it gives me an error:   `code $('.option-filter').click(function() {
            var packageFilter = $('#packages').val();
      var categoryFilter = $('#categories').val(); 
        
     featureList.filter(function(item) {
      if (  (item.values().packageid == 0)  && (item.values().categoryid == 0) ){
       featureList.filter();
       return false;
       }  else {
     return item.values().packageid === packageFilter  || item.values().categoryid === categoryFilter;
     }
  });`

Comment: what is error?  hard to follow without being able to see html and more of the functions code

Answer (score 0):

This post helped me a lot so I thought I would add this here incase someone else tries to do what I have.

First the JS for list.js:

```
/*
* Filtering
*/
var options = {
  valueNames: ['name','phone','status','street','tier','type','zip','zone'],
  plugins: [
    ['fuzzySearch']
  ]
}
var featureList = new List('directory-list', options)

$('.search-fuzzy').keyup(function(){
  featureList.fuzzySearch($(this).val());
});

$('#filter-select').on('click', 'a.filters', function(e){
  if(this.id == 'filter-type-any' || this.id == 'filter-status-any' || this.id == 'filter-zone-any'){
    $(this).addClass('active').parent().siblings().children().removeClass('active')
  } else {
    $(this).toggleClass('active')
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.any').removeClass('active')
  }
  var activeFilters = []
  $('#filter-select').find('a.active').each(function(i) {
    if (this.getAttribute('data-match')){
      activeFilters.push(this.getAttribute('data-match'))
      }
    })
  if(activeFilters.length) {
    var anyType   = (($.inArray('resident', activeFilters) + $.inArray('business', activeFilters) + $.inArray('school', activeFilters)) == -3) ? true : false;
    var anyStatus = (($.inArray('current', activeFilters)  + $.inArray('expiring', activeFilters) + $.inArray('expired', activeFilters) + $.inArray('never', activeFilters)) == -4) ? true : false;
    var anyZone   = (($.inArray('zone1', activeFilters) + $.inArray('zone2', activeFilters) + $.inArray('zone3', activeFilters) + $.inArray('zone4', activeFilters) + $.inArray('zone5', activeFilters) + $.inArray('zone6', activeFilters) + $.inArray('zone7', activeFilters) + $.inArray('zone8', activeFilters)) == -8) ? true : false;
    featureList.filter(function(item) {
      if (
        ( anyType || ($.inArray(item.values().type.toLowerCase(), activeFilters) > -1) )
        &&
        ( anyStatus || ($.inArray(item.values().status.toLowerCase(), activeFilters) > -1) )
        &&
        ( anyZone || ($.inArray(item.values().zone.toLowerCase(), activeFilters) > -1) ) )
      {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    })
  } else {
    featureList.filter()
  }
})
```

Directory Filter Controls

```
#directory-filters
  .row-fluid
    input.search-fuzzy(placeholder='Search')
  #filter-select.row-fluid
    .span6
      h5 Type
      ul#filter-type
        li
          a#filter-type-any.filters.any.active(href='#') All Entries
        li
          a#filter-type-people.filters(href='#', data-match='resident') People
        li
          a#filter-type-business.filters(href='#', data-match='business') Business
        li
          a#filter-type-schools.filters(href='#', data-match='school') Schools
      br
      h5 Status
      ul#filter-status
        li
          a#filter-status-any.filters.any.active(href='#') Any Status
        li
          a#filter-status-member.filters(href='#', data-match='current') Members
        li
          a#filter-status-expiring.filters(href='#', data-match='expiring') Expiring
        li
          a#filter-status-expired.filters(href='#', data-match='expired') Expired
        li
          a#filter-status-never.filters(href='#', data-match='never') Never Member
    .span6
      h5 Zone
      ul#filter-zone
        li
          a#filter-zone-any.filters.any.active(href='#') All Zones
        li
          a#filter-zone-1.filters(href='#', data-match='zone1') Zone 1
        li
          a#filter-zone-2.filters(href='#', data-match='zone2') Zone 2
        li
          a#filter-zone-3.filters(href='#', data-match='zone3') Zone 3
        li
          a#filter-zone-4.filters(href='#', data-match='zone4') Zone 4
        li
          a#filter-zone-5.filters(href='#', data-match='zone5') Zone 5
        li
          a#filter-zone-6.filters(href='#', data-match='zone6') Zone 6
        li
          a#filter-zone-7.filters(href='#', data-match='zone7') Zone 7
        li
          a#filter-zone-8.filters(href='#', data-match='zone8') Zone 8
```

Answer (score 0):

this will do it:

```
$('#filter-clothes').click(function() {
    featureList.filter(function(item) {
        var colour = $("#colour").text();
        var items = $("#items").text();
        if (item.values().colour == colour && item.values().items == items) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

just make sure colour and items are in the filter options

```
var options = { valueNames: [ 'colour', 'listT items ype' ] };
var featureList = new List('viewList', options);
```